# nginx and .htaccess are working together, is this possible?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx

I am encountering an odd situation that appears to be to good to be true.  I have a vps set up with nginx installed/activated for a couple of test domains.

From what i have read, the .htaccess files don't work with nginx.  But apparently the .htaccess file/directives are working for me under nginx.

I verified this by going to netcraft.com and it shows that the webserver is nginx, ab bench also shows nginx as the webserver.  But the .htaccess file still can be read.  For example, I can deny/allow access, or redirect using the .htaccess file.

Am I misunderstanding the information?  nginx webserver can still read .htaccess files and execute directives?

Answer (score 0):

Yea it's possible but there's a trick, the server has both apache and nginx installed, nginx listens to port 80 and apache listens on any other port, nginx would serve the assets directly ( CSS, JS, HTML, etc ) and pass the PHP or whatever app it is to apache, reduces the load on apache a bit, but consumes a little bit more memory because you have 2 servers running.

Comment: thanks for taking the time, but that is not related to the observation posed in my post.

Comment: ok so what am i missing ? because apache is the actual backend server it processes htaccess files but because nginx is a proxy the user will feel that nginx is the server and it's handling htaccess files